# Call ASP from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm trying to figure out, how can i call ASP (NOT asp.net) site/page/etc with javascript.
The ASP is external file and JS is inside of HTML code.

ASP function is intended to use delete function, which deletes selected row from database.
How can i do it without changing the page in browser?

And PLEASE, tell me, if you know some another way to do this, i'm still learning ASP.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but by *far* the most common way is to use `XMLHttpRequest`, often called AJAX. For example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "delete.asp", true);
xhr.send("id=" + rowID);
```

Comment: Thank you, i try to figure out, how can i use that :)

Comment: What should i put in the `<script>` code?
    `<script>

     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("POST", "delete.asp", true);
     xhr.send("id=" + rowID);

     document.write("<a href="#">X</a>");

     </script>`
That X is button, that deletes the row.

Comment: btw, how can i edit that code string in here look like your answer code?

Comment: @TeemuLaine: Comments aren't supposed to have big code blocks, so you can't. In a question or answer, you prefix every line with four spaces. Anyway, you'd probably put it in a function in the `head`: `function deleteRow(rowID) { /* stuff in my answer */ }` Then you could have links like `<a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(<%= Row.ID %>);return false;">X</a>`